# laravel - adding custom files in the public folder

Tags: laravel

I am trying to add custom css and js files to the laravel public folder and I dont want to use the the default css and js folders.  I created a folder and tried linking to it with my blade and its returning a 404

```
<!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

adding open-iconic-bootstrap.css to the css folder works but I am trying to use a customer folder.  Am I missing a step on getting this to work?

Comment: Laravel really has nothing to do with serving files out of the public directory, that's just where the web server root should be.   asset() is a wrapper that prefixes your APP_URL.

Comment: Replace `css/app.css` with your custom directory?

Comment: Have you set the correct directory permissions for the newly created directory and files?

Answer (score 1):

404 is `app.css` or `open-iconic-bootstrap.css` ?

you don't need link the `css\app.css` and `js\app.js`

and delete the line `<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">`

check the correct path `open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.css`